# Error in array declaration grammar

Tags: yacc

```
%token DIGIT RETURN IDENTIFIER COLON COMMA ELSE IF NL KEYWORD BR READ  WRITE WHILE EQUAL
%start y2
%left '-'
%left '+'
%right '='
%%
stmt1:KEYWORD IDENTIFIER X1 //for initialization.
;
y2:stmt1 stmt2 //y2 is starting variable
|
;
X1:COLON {printf(" for int a/ char a");} 
|'['DIGIT']'COLON {printf("for array declarations");} 
;
stmt2:KEYWORD IDENTIFIER"("stmt3")"stmt5 {printf("for functions");} 
|
;
stmt3:KEYWORD IDENTIFIER X2 
| 
;
X2:stmt4 {printf("for parameter int/char");} 
|"["DIGIT"]"COLON {printf("for parameter int arr[]/char arr[]");} //in this production parser is not responding
;
stmt4:COMMA stmt3 {printf("to have multiple arguments");} 
|
;
%%
```

I am parsing string `int a[10];`
 but it instead of parsing, 
execute `yyerror()` every time.
This code parses `int a;` single statement `char a;` also.

Comment: Using meaningful production names and a bit of whitespace would make your grammar *much* easier to read. (For example, don't use `stmt` for something which is not a statement.) It might not make any difference to you, but it will help anyone trying to help you (or grade your work, if it is homework.)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your lexer returns `'['` when it sees an open bracket.

Mixing single-quoted tokens like `'['` and named tokens like `COLON` is confusing and suggests you are copy-and-pasting from different sources, rather than actually designing a program. Since the lexer and parser must agree on the handling of tokens, this form of creating programs is error-prone. I recommend using single-quoted single-character tokens throughout, since it is more readable and simplifies the lexer.

With respect to `X2`, there is a difference between `'['` and `"["`. You probably want the first one. The same problem is found in `stmt2`, which uses​ `"("` and `")"` instead of the single-quoted versions.

Comment: the `%start y2` means that `stmt1` is not the start symbol, so `stmt2` is used...